# @Query("{'ao.status': ?0, 'ao.otp_type': ?1}") void updateOtpStatus(String otpStatus, String otpType); query is giving null result what can be ans

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, oauth-2.0

give a query for mongodb to update the status of certain rows in a database table named "auth_otp". It will change the status to 'INACTIVE' for rows that match the provided otpStatus and otpType

Tried this-
@Query("{'ao.status': ?0, 'ao.otp_type': ?1}")
    void updateOtpStatus(String otpStatus, String otpType);

expected - want updated rows or updated data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A general remark: it seems like you are trying to merge a command (change the state) and a query (retrieve the state) at the same time. This is generally not recommended, but of course I don't know your exact use-case.

This being said, if your query is located in a repository extending [`MongoRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html), you can do operations like save, find, delete, count, exists, ... (and use customize those by using attributes of your entity, see [Defining Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details).

However, if you want to leverage more specific MongoDB capabilities like updating or upserting, you would better use `MongoTemplate` or `MongoOperations`

```
@Component
public class RepositoryImpl {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public RepositoryImpl (MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    public void updateMulti(...) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(...);
        Update update = new Update();
        update.set(...);
        UpdateResult updateResult = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Entity.class);
    }
}
```

Do note that `update`, `updateMulti` or `upsert` will not return the updated data, but the can get the modifiedCount from the `UpdateResult`.